# why im geting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle, fragmenttransaction

I'm using MVP pattern in my code.In `Activity onCreate()` im calling  a method of presenter which has a service call. On response of service call
i throw a callback to ask activity that service has done its work and do change fragment.For a while all works fine,i can see the fragment which has loaded on response of service. But problem is, when i press the back button of a device and reopens the activity ,app gets crash for the line `transaction.commit()` saying

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

please help me to find a fix

thank you

Comment: Please post your activity code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you dont unsubscribe in onDestroy from previous activity?

Comment: i have only one activity.No any other activity is been called.

Comment: but when u close your app its recreate activity

Comment: ok thank you,i did not understand what to unsubscribe.Do you talking about broadcast receiver..?

Comment: no actually for the first time it works fine but when press back button and relaunch the app,it throws an exception and gets crash when doing fragment transactions commit operation

Answer (score 1):

Change your onBackPressed method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (isComeFromLogin) {
        finish();
    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens even with non-MVP applications. I don't the reason but you can override **onBackPressed** method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
   //super.onBackPressed(); //Keep it as it is and finish activity

    finish();

}
```

Comment: thanks user12345, bus i already done with the onBackPressed override, but no luck